# how to generate random points influenced by underlaying variable in R?

Tags: raster, r, point, random

I am wondering if in R is it possible to generate a set of random points, within a given study area, with points' intensity being inhomogeneous, i.e. varying according to an underlying variable? The latter would be represented by a RasterLayer object (e.g., a poulation density raster).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate I'll make a raster with the values 1 to 12 and create 100 points inhomogeneously in the raster with those relative probabilities. Note this does not produce points with exactly those relative counts, each cell is actually a Poisson random number (I think instead of using `sample` to get cell indexes you could use `rpoisson` to get counts, but I digress).

There's probably an R function in a package to do this, but the process is fairly straightforward and I can usually implement this faster than I can find the darn function in a package. Of course I may write a buggy version but hey ho....

A weighted sample of raster cell indexes can be computed from `sample` with replacement, using the raster value as the `prob=` argument:

```
> r = raster(matrix(1:12,3,4))
> set.seed(23) # make this all reproducible
> cell = sample(1:ncell(r),100, prob=r[], replace=TRUE)
> head(cell)
[1]  7  8  4  3  6 11
```

Then you can get the centre of those cells with `xyFromCell`:

```
> centres = xyFromCell(r,cell)
> head(centres)
         x         y
[1,] 0.625 0.5000000
[2,] 0.875 0.5000000
[3,] 0.875 0.8333333
[4,] 0.625 0.8333333
```

Then the final step is to add `U(-0.5*res[1], 0.5*res[1])` to the X coordinate, and similar with `res[2]` to the Y coordinate where `U` is a uniform distribution and `res[]` is the cell width and height.

```
> rx = centres[,1] + runif(nrow(centres), -0.5*res(r)[1], 0.5*res(r)[1])
> ry = centres[,2] + runif(nrow(centres), -0.5*res(r)[2], 0.5*res(r)[2])
> plot(r)
> points(rx,ry)
```

[image]

The uniform distribution within a cell can result in hard borders at cell edges if you have a large number in a cell. If that's a problem you need to think about why you are sampling these points.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide the actual code. I will try it and see what happens.